# Limit in a sense of distributions

Tags: limits, distribution-theory

How to find $\lim_{a\rightarrow\infty} f_a$ in $D'(R)$, for $a>0$, where $f_a:R\rightarrow R$ is defined by

$f_a(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{\sin{ax}}{x}&x\neq 0 \\0&x=0\end{cases}$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to calculate for $\phi\in D(R)$ 
$$ \lim_{a\to\infty} \int_R \frac{\sin ax}{x} \phi(x) dx $$
which is well-defined as the integrand is continuous. Substituting $y=ax$, the integral becomes
$$ \int_R \frac{\sin y}{y}\phi(\frac{y}{a}) dy. $$
As $\phi(\frac{y}{a}) = \phi(0) + \frac{y}{a}\phi'(\xi_y)$ for some $\xi_y$, you have
$$ \int_R \frac{\sin y}{y}\phi(\frac{y}{a}) dy = \pi\phi(0) + \frac{1}{a} \int_R \sin y \phi'(\xi_y) dy.$$
The latter integral is bounded independently of $a$, so you conclude
$$ \lim_{a\to\infty} \frac{\sin ax}{x} = \pi\delta.$$

Comment: I am pretty new with this sort of problems, but as far I know function $\sin x/ x$ isn't Lebesgue integrable on $\mathbb{R}$. Your final answer is correct, but I am not sure that this is right way to obtain it. (I know other way, it is similar)

Comment: @Cortizol Sure it is not Lebesgue integrable. But what's the problem about it?

Comment: Dear @Vobo, please correct me if I am wrong, but I don't think we can say that $\int_R \frac{\sin y}{y} \phi (0) \, dy = \phi(0) \int_R \frac{\sin y}{y}\, dy = \pi \phi(0)$ because second integral is not Lebesgue. As far I know, we work here with Lebesgue integral.

Comment: @Cortizol I never said this. I used Taylor for $\phi(\frac{y}{a})$ and estimated the remainder integral for $a\to 0$.

Comment: Dear @Vobo, I am confused now. Didn't you in $\int_R \frac{\sin y}{y} \phi(\frac{y}{a})\,dy$ change $\phi(\frac{y}{a})$ with $\phi(0)+\frac{y}{a} \phi'(\xi_y)$? If yes, then you used result from my second comment (or not?) (and you thought $a \to \infty$, but that is all right)

Comment: @Cortizol Now I understand your point. But in fact, for each the $a$ the integral is on a finite domain, and the Lebesgue integral of $\int_{-c}^c \frac{\sin y}{y} dy$ converges to $\pi$ as $c\to\infty$.