# Finding limit in D'(R)

Tags: distribution-theory

How to find $\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow 0+} f_\varepsilon$ in $D'(R)$, if $f_\varepsilon(x)=\frac{\sin{\varepsilon x}}{x}$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have answered this here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370480/limit-in-a-sense-of-distributions

Comment: Therefore I suggest to close it as duplicate.

Comment: It is not duplicate, $\varepsilon\rightarrow 0$

Comment: Oh, your right, but it is not difficult. Wait a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By substitution $\varepsilon x\mapsto y$ the expression becomes for a test function $\phi$
$$
\int_{\varepsilon\operatorname{supp }\phi} \frac{\sin y}{y} \phi(\frac{y}{\varepsilon}) dy
$$
for all $\varepsilon<1$. Noting the bounded integrand is bounded, this expression converges to $0$ as $\varepsilon\operatorname{supp }\phi$ shrinks to $\{0\}$. To summarize:
$$
\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0_+} \frac{\sin \varepsilon x}{x} = 0 \text{ in } \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}).
$$

Comment: But, I think that result should be $0$. How you got result $\pi\phi(0)$?

Comment: @alans For $y=0$ the pointwise limit is $\int \frac{\sin y}{y}\phi(0) dy$.

Comment: @alans Wait, the support shrinks too. Let me edit the answer.